# F# Type providers printing

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm currently trying out the `SqlDataConnection` type provider, and was wondering how to display these types.

Is there some way I can have my calls to `printfn "%A"` display something more meaningful than the type name?

Comment: Have you attempted annotating the type provider with a `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to intercept the behaviour of `printfn "%A"` for existing types generated by a type provider (that you cannot modify). If you could modify the type provider, then you could change it to generate the `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute for the generated types, but that's not possible for `SqlDataConnection`.

If you're using it in F# Interactive, then you can use `fsi.AddPrintTransformer` to define how individual values are printed when they are a result of some computation. For example:

```
// Using Northwind database as a sample
type DB = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Northwind;...">
let db = DB.GetDataContext()

// A simple formatter that creates a list with property names and values
let formatAny (o:obj) = 
  [ for p in o.GetType().GetProperties() ->
      p.Name, p.GetValue(o) ]

// Print all Northwind products using the formatter
fsi.AddPrintTransformer(fun (p:DB.ServiceTypes.Products) ->
  formatAny p |> box)

// Take the first product - will be printed using custom formatter
query { for p in db.Products do head }
```

The specified `PrintTransformer` is only used when you get the value as a result in F# interactive. It will also work when you write `query { .. } |> List.ofSeq` for queries that return multiple objects. But for `printfn "%A"`, you'll have to call the conversion function (like `formatAny`) explicitly...